# Can I get Ipopt's version from the C++ interface?

Tags: ipopt, cyipopt

I can get Ipopt's version from an executable via the command line: `ipopt --version`. However, I would like to get the version from the c++ interface, which does not use the executable. Is this possible?

For context, I have installed Ipopt following the standard instructions (on the GitHub repo) and am running the cpp example included:

https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/blob/stable/3.14/examples/Cpp_example/cpp_example.cpp

on Ubuntu 18.04.

My end goal is to get the Ipopt version used by CyIpopt, which links against `libipopt.so` similarly to the c++ interface, so I thought that this was a good first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version is defined in `IpoptConfig.h` as `IPOPT_VERSION`.